# Proof: First Isomorphic Theorem (Injectivity)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, alternative-proof, group-isomorphism

I am unable to prove injectivity for the first isomorphic theorem. A website shows the proof as follows:
Map: $ϕ(xN) = ψ(x)$
ϕ is injective:

$ϕ(xN)=ϕ(yN)\iff ψ(x) = ψ(y)\iff eH = ψ(x)^{-1} ψ(y) = ψ(x^{-1}) ψ(y) = ψ(x^{-1}y)\iff x^{-1}y\in N \iff xN = yN$

I don't understand how $x^{−1}y ∈ N ⇐⇒ xN = yN$ imply that $\phi$ is injective?

Also, is there an alternative way to show that $\phi$ is injective by concluding that x=y?

Note: N here denotes the kernel of $ψ$

Comment: Better notation for equivalence arrow: \iff

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$ϕ(xN) = ϕ(yN)\Longrightarrow xN = yN.$$
So $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: But how do we get here $x^{−1}y ∈ N ⇐⇒ xN = yN$ why does this imply that xN = yN?

Comment: $xN=yN$ gives, multiplying by $x^{-1}$, $N=x^{-1}yN$, so that $x^{-1}y\in N$, and conversely.

Comment: This is however not trivial, since we are dealing with sets.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand . :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems your trouble is in understanding that if $N$ is a normal subgroup, then $$xN=yN \iff x^{-1}y \in N.$$

Let $xN=yN.$ Then $N=x^{-1}yN.$  Since, $N$ is a subgroup, therefore it contains the identity, say $e.$ Thus, $(x^{-1}y)e \in x^{-1}yN=N.$ So, $x^{-1}y \in N.$

Conversely, let $x^{-1}y \in N.$ Again, since $N$ is a subgroup therefore, $x^{-1}yN \subseteq N.$ Thus, $yN\subseteq xN.$ Since, two cosets are either disjoint or identical, therefore $xN=yN.$